# Move tableview below top tab bar

Tags: uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I want to move my table view below tabbar. Presently first row of the tableview is getting hidden behind the tab bar.

I tried

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.tableView.frame.origin.y = 50
    print("done")
}
```

I tried the same in viewDidLoad and viewWilAppear

Kindly help me with this

[Screen Shot of TabBar with TablView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2IVT.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in your `ViewDidLoad()`method in your view controller. It will move the TableViewController to begin after the navigation bar. However, you will also need to subtract the status bar that is above your navigation bar so I have also added that for you.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - 20, 0, 0, 0)
```

Cheers.

Comment: I modified ur solution and below worked for me
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(TabBarHytVar, 0, 0, 0)